# JQuery - not first

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I say..

```
On Click .not.first() div
alert('Yeah you clicked a div which is not the first one!');
```

My actual code:

```
this.$('thumbnails').children().click(function() {

                $('#video').animate({width: 164, height: 20, top: 475, marginLeft: 262},0)

       $('.flv').animate({left: 2222, opacity: '0'},0).css('display', 'none')
        $('.close').animate({opacity: '0'},0)
                clicked = 0

            });
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your current `click` handler?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There's a [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) (greater-than-index) selector or [`.slice(1)`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) (@[bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince)'s preference :), your question translated literally would be:

```
$("div:gt(0)").click(function() {
  alert('Yeah you clicked a div which is not the first one!');
});
//or...
$("div").slice(1).click(function() {
  alert('Yeah you clicked a div which is not the first one!');
});
```

For your updated question:

```
$('thumbnails').children(":gt(0)").click(function() {
   $('#video').css({width: 164, height: 20, top: 475, marginLeft: 262});
   $('.flv').css({left: 2222, opacity: '0'}).hide();
   $('.close').css({opacity: '0'});
   clicked = 0;
});
//or...
$('thumbnails').children().slice(1).click(function() {
   $('#video').css({width: 164, height: 20, top: 475, marginLeft: 262});
   $('.flv').css({left: 2222, opacity: '0'}).hide();
   $('.close').css({opacity: '0'});
   clicked = 0;
});
```

Note the use of [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), if you want to make instant non-animated style changes, use this istead.

Comment: Why would you use this over a combination of not and the first selector?

Comment: @Justin - Faster, less to type, fewer objects created? :)

Comment: @downvoter - care to comment?  This is both correct and shorter...so I'm curious.

Comment: @Nick - Makes sense. The former seems more readable (which is typically where I default to unless there are performance issues). Needless to say that I don't work on optimizing JavaScript very much.

Comment: +1 for respecting the [commandments](https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Commandments/blob/master/jquery_commandments.json) !

Comment: In general avoid putting a non-CSS-standard-selector like `:gt` in an expression that is otherwise standard. Using any non-standard feature means the whole selector will have to be resolved using the Sizzle JS selector engine instead of the fast native `querySelectorAll` API. Typically it is better to use a standard selector combined with a filtering function. There is no `gt()` function, but `$('div').slice(1)` would do the same thing.

Comment: @bobince - While I don't disagree in principal, you're also creating another jQuery object doing that.  More so, I find the point moot here, since `:first` *isn't a valid CSS selector either*, it's jQuery specific.

Answer (score 8):

```
$(div).not(":first").click(function(){
   alert("Yeah you clicked a div which is not the first one!);
});
```

see [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and [.not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) from the jquery docs.

```
$('thumbnails').children().not(":first").click(function() {
    $('#video').animate({width: 164, height: 20, top: 475, marginLeft: 262},0)
    $('.flv').animate({left: 2222, opacity: '0'},0).css('display', 'none')
    $('.close').animate({opacity: '0'},0)
        clicked = 0
});
```

Would be the answer for the update to your question.

Comment: Why fire up the selector engine *again* for this?  There's no need, in fact it's very wasteful to do so.

Comment: No worries, but as pointed out by Nick below, you would be better off using .css rather than .animate if you need instant animations.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#id").not(':first').click(function(){
alert('Not the first');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').not(':first').click(function() {
    alert('Yeah you clicked a div which is not the first one!');
});
```

For your updated question:

```
$('thumbnails').children().not(':first').click(function() {

    $('#video').animate({width: 164, height: 20, top: 475, marginLeft: 262},0)
    $('.flv').animate({left: 2222, opacity: '0'},0).css('display', 'none')
    $('.close').animate({opacity: '0'},0)
    clicked = 0
});
```